# Xamarin form: WkWebView not loading website

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview

Hi am using the Sample code from Xamarin (Hybrid WebView)

```
public class Test : WKNavigationDelegate
{ 
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {

    }
}

public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null) {
            userController = new WKUserContentController ();
            var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript (script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            config.WebsiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore;

            var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new Test();
            SetNativeControl (webView); 
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", "index.html"));
            Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false))); 


        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
}
```

The code can run the html file stored locally in the Content folder in the app. When I change to new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://www.google.com", false))); The page is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Have a look at this part of code in custom renderer:

```
if (e.NewElement != null) {
        string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", "index.html"));
        Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));    
    }
```

The url here is combining a local path in the app. So, it will load a local Html successfully and won't work when your change to `new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://www.google.com", false)))`.

So, if you want to load a website, you should change the code to :

```
if (e.NewElement != null) {
       //string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
       //Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));

       //test
       //Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://preview.pro.ant.design/user/login")));

       Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (Element.Uri)));    
   }
```

Comment: @LittleFunny Glad to hear that. I answered another your question about webView appears blank before,  the same cause as here?